# grep and grep -v simultaneously

Tags: linux, grep

I have to grep a pretty huge text file (~15GB) for 3 different strings. The important thing to be noted is the three strings say X,Y and Z comprise about 99.9 % of the text file and are mutually exclusive.

i.e X + Y + Z + .01% junk = complete file

So Is there any way I can reduce the time by doing grep and grep -v function simultaneously 
Hence the flow of logic should be:

```
grep X filename.txt >> linescontainingstringX.
somehow do grep Y and grep Z on the remaining file ie grep Y >> linesnotcontainingstringX
```

Please let me know if there is a method for me.

Comment: I think you should open the file using Perl and write the code for the same to achieve your logic.

Comment: @Raghuram - I guess you haven't heard of `egrep` either ...

Comment: @Brian, I guess you didn't notice that he's trying to create **two** output files: one with the X lines and one with the Y|Z lines.  You can't do that in one pass with `egrep`, but you can in Perl (probably `awk`, too).

Comment: @Brian, I am aware of egrep. It will allow me to do grep operation in either X or Y or Z format. What I need is to separate a file into two parts : one containing X string and one not containing the X string.I am aware that I can do this by doing grep and grep -v one by one. What i want is to achieve it with one command.

Comment: @Raghuram: I am also aware that this can be done easily in perl or any programming language by the logic: read line() , if line matched X save it to filecontainingx , else save it to filenotconatiningx. But i have already written  a bash script for my whole purpose and I don't want to run a perl script from within my bash script.Hence this question. My ultimate aim is to save some time and CPU cycles as currently i am doing grep and grep -v one after the other.

Comment: grep can't output to anything else than to a single file: standard output. You want multiple files with one command, you can't use grep.

Answer (score 2):

Use perl.

```
perl -n -e 'BEGIN{ open XFILE,">x.txt" or die "$!" ; open YFILE,">y.txt"  or die "$!"; open ZFILE, ">z.txt" or die "$!";} print XFILE $_ if /X/; print YFILE $_ if /Y/; print ZFILE $_ if /Z/;'
```

Comment: @ Raghuram: I was thinking of going the perl scripting way when i saw your suggestion. Completely forgot that perl had command line execution also.

Answer (score 0):

use `egrep` and a regular expression that matches X OR Y OR Z.

http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~tal/3261/fall07/handout/egrep_mini-tutorial.htm

egrep 'X|Y|Z` myFile.txt

Comment: this results in only one file, not one per pattern